# How to get proxy address from browser settings?

Tags: networking, proxy

I work behind a proxy and as a consequence, I had do configure my browser to let it know the proxy adress (`my_proxy`)and port (`1234`). I did with manual configuration.
It looks like this :
[image]

However, some other softwares need the proxy adress. I tried `http://my_proxy:1234`, but it doesn't work.

During my researchs, I often found examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144289/installing-python-modules-through-proxy) where sample proxy adress looks like this : `http://user:password@proxy.com:1234`

Could you tell me a way to know this http address ?

EDIT : I forgot to precise this, but I work on windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have any command line tools that need access to your proxy, do not forget the trailing "/", i.e.:

`export http_proxy=http://my_proxy:1234/`

As configuring your proxy inside of Firefox without user and password seems to work fine, you wont'd need user:password inside that export-clause.

Comment: Doing so gives me this error : `Download error: InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: '1234/'`

Comment: I forgot: `export http_proxy=http://my_proxy:1234/`

Comment: If I do a `set`, here is what it looks like : `http_proxy=http://my_proxy:1234/`
However, I still have troubles using some softwares. Other like firefox and maven work but have special configuration files.